# List of functions as parameter of function (R)

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have a problem: I need to run the same function over and over, but with different parameters, inside another function. How can I implement it straightforwardly, because the manual method I'm doing currently produces very much code and makes my code unreadable?

Pseudocode:

```
internal_func <- function(x, y, z)

external_func <- function(list_of_functions) {
   # do some stuff

   for(i in 1:length(list_of_functions)){
      # evaluate the internal function and save the results in a matrix
   }

   # do some more stuff
   return(stuff)
}

# run 1
# generate list of internal_func with varying x and pass it to external_func

# run 2
# generate list of internal_func with varying y and pass it to external_func

# run 3
# generate list of internal_func with varying y and pass it to external_func
```

**EDIT**: Some more explanation:
My internal function runs a simulation 100 times and gives me for example the mean of the population sizes of all the simulations. The individual simulations take in a set of parameters and return a matrix of all time steps.

In the outer function want to measure for example the mean of a population of simulations where I only change one parameter of the simulation at a time. And afterward, generate a plot of it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) strongly recommend `seq_along(list_of_functions)` instead of `1:length(.)`, safer/defensive when it is feasible that `list_of_functions` is empty. (2) Is it safe to assume something like `list_of_functions <- list(min, mean, max)`? (3) I don't know how this all ties together, perhaps you can add some substance to this and make it reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

just guessing at what might be useful to you; finding it hard to guess from your pseudo code...
anyway here is some small code that manufactures a list of functions each with a different parameter (that varies how many numbers they will generate); these are passed to an outerfunction that operates on their results

```
library(purrr)

my_partials <- map(1:5,\(x_)
    partial(.f=rnorm,n=x_))

outerfunc <- function(func){
  round(func(),0)
}
map(my_partials,outerfunc)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1]  1 -1

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[4]]
[1]  1  0  0 -1

[[5]]
[1] -1  2  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understood properly your question, but as I understand it is a good way to explain Applicative functors, so I wrote some code with Scala.

Applicative functors have `ap` function with the following signature:

`def ap[A, B](ff: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B]`

F being a functor, like `List`, in fact `List` is an applicative functor!

So we can write:

prelude:

```
import cats.implicits._

type X = Int
type Y = Int
type Z = Int
type R = Int
```

cats gives us the applicative instance for `List`, and the type aliases so we have nice code next:

```
val f: X => Y => Z => R = x => y => z => x + y + z
val g: X => Y => Z => R = x => y => z => x - y - z

val internal_func = List(f, g)

// generate list of internal_func with varying x
((internal_func ap List(1, 2, 3)) ap List(5)) ap List(40)
// res36: List[R] = List(46, 47, 48, -44, -43, -42)

// generate list of internal_func with varying y
((internal_func ap List(10)) ap List(3, 4, 5)) ap List(2)
// res37: List[R] = List(15, 16, 17, 5, 4, 3)

// generate list of internal_func with varying z
((internal_func ap List(20)) ap List(3)) ap List(4,5,6)
// res38: List[R] = List(27, 28, 29, 13, 12, 11)
```

The result is not so clean, I'm sure it could be improved.
But the idea is the first 3 entries are f(x, y, z) varying one variable, and the second 3 are g(x, y, z) varying one variable.

It can even be done in just one execution setting all variations in together, but the reading is not so clear for this explanation.

I hope it fits your question! The inline `ap` would be replacing your for loop so you can still do stuff before and after.